# Why Doctrine Cache do not save raw php arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, caching, doctrine

I am using Doctrine Cache for my project and I am using it's PhpFileCache driver.
https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/1.10.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/PhpFileCache.php

and I can't understand why it is not saving any of my data just in raw php array? instead it is save all of them like a serialised data with function to unserialise them.
https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/1.10.x/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/PhpFileCache.php#L87-L93

```
    if (is_object($data) && method_exists($data, '__set_state')) {
        $value = var_export($value, true);
        $code  = sprintf('<?php return %s;', $value);
    } else {
        $value = var_export(serialize($value), true);
        $code  = sprintf('<?php return unserialize(%s);', $value);
    }
```

I see. That there is some additional check here and all my data don't pass this condition for some reason, but if I will just leave this code:

```
        $value = var_export($value, true);
        $code  = sprintf('<?php return %s;', $value);
```

it will save a raw php arrays in cache from all of my data and it is works.

Why this is happens? Why this condition do not works for me?

Comment: That code is the result of two commits ([this](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/commit/b586193de2ee266fbcd73fed6ca90fa4f1c47008) and [this](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/commit/a2f4d4447de45482dcb4f46b606d352ddc882c20)) regarding objects without `__set_state()` implementation and arrays of them. I'm confused as why the second one seems to undo the first one but I'm not familiar with this library, let alone its codebase.

Comment: I am confused too :(

So I have decided to create my own varian of php array cache driver for doctrine and include it instead of this from doctrine

https://github.com/flextype/flextype/commit/66aa2dcc11cb44bb42e0021d4c8dca27241b78c6